# Have there been Announcements of New Star Wars Books or Comics, Tie Ins for The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

I just saw the movie, and I can see that they can go crazy and make a lot of tie ins. 
Maybe

New Series (Since the Mandalorian seems to be going great)

Or the clasic approach
Comics or Novels.

Are there any plans or have they already announced that they will indeeed make this?

Comment: What do you mean by tie-ins? There have been a ton of lead-in novels and comics already released under the 'Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker' title. Under the new canon model w/ the Lucasfilm Story Group, it's not really accurate (imo) to call things 'tie-ins' since it's all canon at this point. One could argue that Episode 7 of The Mandalorian (which was released on 12/18 in the US, a few days before normal Mandaorlian release day of Friday) was very loosely related / foreshadowing of certain events in RoS, and thus was it was released a little early to set that up

Comment: I actually did not knew those existed, is there a timeline of publication online?

Answer (score 1):

*Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker* received a considerable number of preview novels, comics and factbooks (plus other materials) under the heading of [*Journey To Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/star-wars-rise-skywalker-publishing-tie-ins-revealed-1207746). This included;

> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: We are the Resistance by
> Elizabeth Schaefer and Alan Baston (Random House Kids/Little Golden
> Books; young reader fiction, Oct. 4 2019)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Resistance Heroes by
> Michael Siglain, Diogo Saito and Luigi Aimé (Disney Lucasfilm Press;
> young reader fiction, Oct. 4)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: First Order Villains by
> Michael Siglain, Diogo Saito and Luigi Aimé (Disney Lucasfilm Press;
> young reader fiction, Oct. 4)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Choose Your Destiny — A
> Finn & Poe Adventure by Cavan Scott and Elsa Charretier (Disney
> Lucasfilm Press; young reader fiction, Oct. 4)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Spark of the Resistance
> by Justina Ireland and Phil Noto (Disney Lucasfilm Press; middle grade
> fiction, Oct. 4)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Resistance by Sally
> Little (Readerlink/Studio Fun, young reader sound book, Oct. 4)
>
> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker Magnetic Playset by Sally Little,
> Diogo Saito and Luigi Aimé (Readerlink/Studio Fun, playset, Oct. 4)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker Search & Find by Sally
> Little, Art Mawhinney, Fabio Piacentini and Ferran Rodriguez
> (Readerlink/Studio Fun, young reader, Oct. 4)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Ultimate Star Wars
> New Edition by Adam Bray, Cole Horton, Tricia Barr, Ryder Windham;
> foreword by Anthony Daniels (DK; non-fiction, Oct. 4)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker — Star Wars: The Ultimate
> Pop-Up Galaxy by Matthew Rienhart and Kevin M. Wilson (Insight
> Editions, pop-up book, Oct. 8)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Allegiance Nos. 1-4 by
> Ethan Sacks and Luke Ross (Marvel; comic book, weekly from Oct. 9)
>
> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Amazing Sticker Adventure (DK;
> sticker book, Oct. 14)
>
> Star Wars Adventures Nos. 27-29 by John Barber, Michael Moreci, Derek
> Charm and Tony Fleecs (IDW Publishing; comic book, monthly from
> October TBD)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Resistance Reborn by
> Rebecca Roanhorse (Del Rey; adult fiction, Nov. 12)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Force Collector by Kevin
> Shinick (Disney Lucasfilm Press; young adult fiction, Nov. 19)
>
> Journey to Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Moviemaking Magic of
> Ships and Battles by Landry Walker (Abrams, non-fiction, Dec. 3)
>
> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Galaxy Needs You by Caitlin
> Kennedy and Eda Kaban (Disney Lucasfilm Press, young reader, Dec. 17)
>
> The Art of Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker by Phil Szostak (Abrams,
> non-fiction, Dec. 20)
>
> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker The Visual Dictionary by Pablo
> Hidalgo (DK, non-fiction, Dec. 20)
>
> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker Official Guide by Matt Jones (DK,
> young reader non-fiction, Dec. 20)
>
> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker Official Movie Special by various
> (Titan, non-fiction, Dec. 20)

Since the film's release, there have also been a [number of books relating directly to the film](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media), including two direct novelisations.

> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker Graphic Novel Adaptation (Slated for
> Jan 2021)
>
> The Rise of Skywalker: Junior Reader Golden Book (Aug. 2020)
>
> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: A Junior Novel (Apr. 2020)
>
> Star Wars Galaxy of Adventures: "Kylo Ren vs. Resistance Rebels" (Apr. 2020)
>
> Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition (Mar. 2020)

Answer (score -4):

I heard "through the grapevine" that Disney is scrapping (possibly re-writing) Episodes 7 to 9, because the films were such a disaster.  For his part, Dave Filoni wants to distance The Mandalorian and The Book of Boba Fett from the crappy Sequel films.  So, don't be surprised if none of Filoni's projects tie into Episodes 7 to 9.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You're also wrong about them de-canonising episode 7-9. These films made a billion dollars each and there's zero chance of it happening.

Comment: @Valorum second this. Plus, this answer is also conjecture with no sourcing behind it. “I heard through the grapevine” is not a legit answer for this SE site.